# App resumes and comes to the foreground unexpectedly

Tags: android

When my app is running in the background under some certain circumstances it comes to the foreground unintentionally. Based on user accounts it has happened when receiving phone calls or when data connectivity changes.

I use google analytics, admob sdk, and couchbase mobile. Any clue as to what would cause an app to come to the foreground without the user doing anything would be helpful

Comment: Have you checked what services your app runs? Could it be a service that receives a Google cloud message and is launching an activity?

Comment: Without explaining more about what application components you have (Activities, BroadcastReceivers, Services etc) it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a service or a receiver running that triggers the activity to start if a certain event occurs. Also check the manifest to see if you have some weird configurations set there

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.